# Divisibility criteria

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Notice that by $\mod 7$ we have $$6!\equiv -1 (\mod 7)$$ $$5!1!\equiv 1 (\mod 7)$$ $$4!2!\equiv -1 (\mod 7)$$ $$3!3!\equiv 1 (\mod 7).$$

- Calculate $10!, 9!1!, 8!2!, 7!3!, 6!4!, 5!5!$ by $\mod11.$
- Then, based on consideration of the foregoing, perform the appropriate theorem and prove it.

I've calculate $$10!\equiv -1 (\mod 11)$$ $$9!1!\equiv 1 (\mod 11)$$ $$8!2!\equiv -1 (\mod 11)$$ $$7!3!\equiv 1 (\mod 11)$$ $$6!4!\equiv -1 (\mod 11)$$ $$5!5!\equiv 1 (\mod 11).$$
I know Wilson's theorem $$(p-1)!\equiv -1 (\mod p)$$ and Leibniz theorem $$(p-2)!\equiv 1 (\mod p),$$ and I assume that $-1$ is for odd numbers $n$ and $1$ is for even numbers $n$ of the equation $$(p-n)!(n-1)!\equiv \pm 1 (\mod p), $$ for $n \geq 1$, but still can not prove it or find a theorem for this.

Do anyone know the theorem for this? Or can anyone help me to perform the appropriate theorem and prove it?

Comment: You can get everything from Wilson.  Look for example at $(p-5)!(4)!$. Note that $4\equiv -(p-4)$, $3\equiv -(p-3)$, $2\equiv -(p-2)$, and $1\equiv -(p-1)$. So $(p-5)!4!\equiv (-1)^4(p-1)!\equiv -1$.

Comment: You are welcome. Basically the same idea is used to produce a solution of $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ when $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$. For we get $(2k)!(2k)!\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that, when we look at this $\mod p$, that we see \begin{align}
(p-n)!(n-1)!&\equiv (p-n)!\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot\cdots\cdot 2\cdot 1\\
&\equiv (-1)^{n-1}\cdot (p-n)!\cdot (-n+1)\cdot (-n+2)\cdot\cdots\cdot -2\cdot -1\\
&\equiv (-1)^{n-1}\cdot (p-n)!\cdot (p-n+1)\cdot (p-n+2)\cdot\cdots\cdot (p-2)\cdot (p-1)\\
&\equiv (-1)^{n-1}\cdot (p-1)!\\
&\equiv (-1)^{n-1}\cdot -1\\
&\equiv (-1)^n\mod p
\end{align}
Thus, as you noticed, $(p-n)!(n-1)!\equiv \pm 1\mod p$. Even more specific, $$(p-n)!(n-1)!\equiv (-1)^n\mod p$$
so that you know exactly when it is plus and when minus one.

Hope this helped!

Comment: But you now for $n=1$ have $(p-1)!0!$ which is not correct. And 'cause of that I assumed that  this equation above works only for $n \rangle 1$.

Comment: Note that $0!=1$ - so my solution gives $(p-1)!0!\equiv (-1)^1\mod p$, which is correct.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Thanks